# FPS drops in Fullscreen mode but fine in Window/Applet?

Tags: java, fullscreen, frame-rate

I've been working on a game engine. It can create games in windowed mode, fullscreen mode or applet mode. The FPS is fine in applet mode and windowed mode (gives me 90-120 fps with upto 3000 objects in the map), but in fullscreen mode, it drops to 25-50 fps. Here's the window class.

https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-java/source/browse/src/com/gej/core/GWindow.java

Could not find where the problem is. And more over running on windows is fine but on Ubuntu it has this problem. Listing the display modes gave me the bit depth -1 Here's the complete list on my machine.

```
1600     900     -1
1440     900     -1
1440     900     -1
1280     800     -1
1280     800     -1
1152     864     -1
1024     768     -1
1024     768     -1
1024     768     -1
832      624     -1
800      600     -1
800      600     -1
800      600     -1
800      600     -1
640      480     -1
640      480     -1
640      480     -1
640      480     -1
720      400     -1
```

I've found that bit depth -1 indicates BIT_DEPTH_MULTI, a constant in the DisplayMode class. So setting the mode increased the fps to 60-70fps but still not as much as in windowed mode.

Comment: What happens if the Window-mode Window is "as big as" the Full Screen?

Comment: Stretching the display (using window mode as fullscreen) gives me the same fps as the fullscreen mode (The graphics need to be scaled)

Comment: Then your problem is that more needs to be drawn.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I only draw the visible objects in the map. Then how that can be?? here's my map class.  https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-java/source/browse/src/com/gej/map/Map.java

Comment: You said, if the window is the same size as the screen, it lags. That means that your card can't handle drawing that many objects. Drawing only what can be seen is a very smart thing to do. But unless you buffer your screen, there is not much to do.

Comment: Engine uses triple buffering. See https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-java/source/browse/src/com/gej/core/Game.java

Comment: Then my current hypothesis is the same as that of Cole Johnson's: it isn't the *number of objects*, but rather it is the *fillrate* that is the limiting factor. Using an engine that takes advantage of hardware better (e.g. OpenGL, or just the "scaling portion" anyway) should solve this. IIRC there were some peculiarities with getting Java2D to actually *use* hardware acceleration...

Comment: I was already scaling all the images in the Game class. Updated source see now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is Java2D using hardware acceleration at all on Ubuntu?  Take a look at some [Java 2d flags](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html), especially at those that turn OpenGL on.

On Windows, Direct3D acceleration is used by default.  On Linux, you *don't* get OpenGL by default so try turning it on by using command line option `-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true` when starting the JVM.

Comment: got this error "i915_program_error: Exceeded max nr indirect texture lookups (6 out of 4)"

Comment: Got it to run at 60-76fps but the error message continues to display

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati Maybe your video card/drivers can't run OpenGL backend for Java2D (reference to this error I found [here](http://linuxhippy.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/opengl-pipeline-works-with-i915-open.html))  If you can't update your video card drivers, you might have to accept that Java2D/OpenGL wont work with your current hardware.

Comment: But the fps has increased lightly. When calling the JVM with option from command-line I had got this error. But when I've placed it in the constructor, I'm getting 60-76 fps and now catching the exceptions didn't give me the error message.